# How to reduce branches in my code as many as possible without changing functionalities in c#?

Tags: c#, branch

```
public static void addpatron()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have selected to add a Patron.");
        string first, last, city, state = "", street, email, temp;
        int zip = 0;
        long number = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a First Name: ");
        first = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a Last Name: ");
        last = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a Street Address: ");
        street = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a City Name: ");
        city = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a Email Id: ");
        email = Console.ReadLine();
        int f = 0;
        while (f == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a State Name: ");
            state = Console.ReadLine();
            if (state.Length == 2)
            {
                Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z][A-Za-z])");
                Match m = r.Match(state);
                if (m.Success)
                    f = 1;
            }
        }
        while (f == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a Zip Code: ");
            temp = Console.ReadLine();
            if (temp.Length == 5)
            {
                Regex r = new Regex(@"([0-9]{5})");
                Match m = r.Match(temp);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    zip = int.Parse(temp);
                    if (zip / 10000 != 0)
                        f = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        while (f == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a Mobile Number: ");
            temp = Console.ReadLine();
            if (temp.Length == 10)
            {
                Regex r = new Regex(@"([0-9]{10})");
                Match m = r.Match(temp);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    number = long.Parse(temp);
                    if (number / 100000000 != 0)
                        f = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        MainClass.patron.Add(MainClass.user, new Info { firstname = first, lastname = last, street = street, state = state, city = city, zip = zip, phone = number, email = email });
        displayUser.display(MainClass.user);
        MainClass.user++;
        MainClass.Menu();
    }
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For breakout a while loop. using a meaningless `f` variable could be replaced with a `while(true) .....   if(success) break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possibilities to shorten your code:

1. You can use the `do {} while (condition);` loop. This way, you can decide whether to leave the loop after the input.
2. You don't need a variable, deciding whether to stop the loop. You can check all conditions (and in your case very easily) in the loop condition.
3. You can check the length of a string with a regex using the `^` = start of string and `$`= end of string anchors and `{5}` as length of the match.
4. You can also simplify the regex to ignore the case.
5. Your division operations seem only to check, that the first digit entered is something different than `0`. You can also check this with the regex.
6. You can use the static `Regex.IsMatch()` method, which returns `true` or `false`.

For instance checking the state

```
do {
   Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a State Name: ");
   state = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!RegEx.IsMatch(state, @"^[a-z]{2}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

Checking the ZIP Code. `int.TryParse()` will only be executed, if the `Regex.Match()` returns `true` and is a convenient way, to parse and assign the value within the expression.

```
do {
   Console.WriteLine("Please Provide a ZIP Code: ");
   tmp = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!(RegEx.IsMatch(tmp, @"^[1-9][0-9]{4}$") && int.TryParse(tmp, out zip)));
```